Using part of table title in set analysis expression Qlik Sense
Is it possible to use/refer to a part of a table (in a dashboard) title in a set analysis expression in Qlik Sense?
Like I want to use the last 3 characters from the table title for example to use in an expression for filtering the data in the table?

Are you talking about a table object in the dashboard or a table from the data model?

The first (table in dashboard)... I added it to the question.

There is no straightforward way to do that. Do you have access to the Script?

There is a Qlik Extension for that - it´s called JoMash and with it you can filter the data and build your own multi-app mashups.
